# Laravel - custom authentification login

Tags: laravel, ldap

I'm using laravel and want to use the built-in authentification system.
One should be able to login in into my app using his/her ldap account. I don't want to copy the ldap users to a local database.
So I wrote a custom UserProvider where I log in into the ldap server:

```
class LdapAuthProvider implements UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveByCredentials (array $credentials)
    {
         // try to connect with given username
        $ldap = new \Adldap\Adldap();
        $ldap->addProvider ( [
            // config stuff based on $credentials ...
        ] );
        try {
            $ldap->connect();
            return new \App\User (['id': $credentials['username']]);
        }
        catch (\Adldap\Auth\BindException $e) {
            return NULL;
        }
}
```

And then registered it in the AuthServiceProvider in the boot method

```
Auth::provider ('ldap', function($app)
{
    return new LdapAuthProvider;
});
```

When I call `Auth::attempt` from my LoginController with correct username and password, the function returns true. But after redirecting to another page, `Auth::check` returns false, so it is not stored in the session that I have logged in successfully.

My config/auth.php looks like this

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'ldap',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

Storing data manually in the session using `Session::put()` works fine.

What do I have to do in order to keep the user logged in after redirect to another page?

Comment: You could use sessions.

Comment: As @sisve and lagbox said (and their comments seems to have been scrubbed), you need to post some more info.

Comment: Your configuration looks reasonable. Does both routes use the web middleware group, or at least the StartSession middleware? Also, are they only using it _once_? Initiating the session twice will make silently fail.

Comment: I addded `->middleware('web')` for the routes in my routes/web.php but still getting the same result as before